# Unable to upload new APK file to Android Play store (google pay)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-permissions

When I try to upload a new apk version of my app, i get this message: "La aplicación que has enviado recientemente se ha rechazado por infringir las Políticas del Programa para Desarrolladores de Google Play. Si has enviado una actualización, la versión anterior sigue estando disponible en Google Play."

After that, i receive and e-mail talking about "Google Pay" but i never used google pay.

> We detected that at least one APK version in your recent upload isn’t
>   using Android Pay correctly. Including APK version(s) 19 in your
>   submission could cause your app to be rejected for violating our
>   Payments policy.
>
> If you’d like to use Android Pay in your app, please follow these
>   steps:
>
> Remove any digital content from your app. To use Android Pay, your app
>   must only sell physical goods or services. Make sure your app is
>   compliant with all policies listed in the Developer Program Policies.
>   Remember that additional enforcement could occur if there are further
>   policy issues with your apps. Sign in to your Developer Console and
>   submit the app. Make sure to increment the version number of the APK.
>   If you’d like to use another payment method in your app, please follow
>   these steps:
>
> Remove  from your manifest. Sign in to your Developer
>   Console and submit the app. Make sure to increment the version number
>   of the APK. Policy issue: Android Pay or other alternative payment
>   mechanisms to Google Play’s in-app billing service are only permitted
>   for the following:
>
> Android Pay For physical goods or services, such as movie tickets.
>   Other alternative payment mechanisms to Google Play’s in-app billing
>   service For physical goods or services, such as movie tickets, or a
>   publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription.
>   For digital goods that may be downloaded to devices and used outside
>   of the app, such as songs that can be played on other music players.
>   Donations to 527 designated tax exempt organizations are also
>   permitted. If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this rejection may
>   have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team. One
>   of my colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.
>
> I appreciate your support of Google Play!
>
> Best,
>
> Byron
>
> Google Play Review Team

In my manifest i had this

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

In the playStore I couldn't see my app for tablet, then, reading in internet, the reason was because i have a permission to CALL_PHONE. After that i add this line to my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

And after that i cant never upload again a new apk version (I  think the permission is not the problem)
Why I have this kind of problem?
Thanks!

Comment: The case may be Your app content not permissions. Also check your apps permission after compile on test device using some kind of manifest viewer app to check if there are no permissions added by gradle automatically from some plugin(I once had issue with permission added to manifest in compile time few months ago).

Comment: `After that, i receive and e-mail talking about "Google Pay" but i never used google play.` what does this mean? Google Pay or Google Play? And if You upload a new version, You have to upgrade your version number in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact them:

> If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this rejection may have been in
>   error, please reach out to our policy support team.

Write back to them. If your explanation/justification is valid they will correct the decision. I've had wrong notifications a few times and with proper explanation the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

We had this problem after we upgrade the play service version, the generated manifest in "app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug" folder includes the following by default:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true" />
```

You have to exclude the google payment in the gradle build file if you are not using it.

Comment: How to exclude it from Gradle?

Comment: You can just put `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="false" />` in your AndroidManifest inside your `application` tag.

Comment: `compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.x.x') {
        exclude module: 'play-services-wallet'
    }` in your gradle file